# Polynomial of degree 5 that has no root in a normal extension, then it is irreducible over that extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

This is a problem from my Qual exams

"Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of fields of characteristic 0. Suppose $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree 5 in $K[x]$ and has no root in $L$. Prove that $f$ is irreducible in $L[x]$."

I usually only deal with normal extension of finite degree. So in this problem it is really hard to understand $L$. Anyway, suppose $f$ is reducible, then it must be a product of a quadratic and a cubic. How does this lead to contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one possible case where
$$f=g_2g_3$$
where $g_2$ and $g_3$ are irreducible over $L$ of degrees $2$ and $3$.
We can assume $g_2$ and $g_3$ are monic. We can assume that $L$ is the Galois
closure of the extension of $K$ generated by the coefficients of the $g_j$, so
is a finite extension of $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $L/K$. Then $f=g_2^\sigma g_3^\sigma$
for any $\sigma\in G$. That's also an irreducible factorisation of $f$
so must be the same as $f=g_2g_3$. Therefore $g_2^\sigma=g_2$ etc.
(this is where we need $g_2$ and $g_3$ to have different degrees). So the coefficients of $g_2$ are fixed by $G$ so lie in $K$, contradicting
$f$ being irreducible over $K$.